# Why chords make melody sound different?

Tags: harmony

I am learning to harmonize melodies. I put basic triads under the melody notes. Sometimes, they work well. Sometimes, the chords just make the melody sound different. I can’t find solution to it.

For example. Melody as the following.

Key: A minor. 3/4

Measure 1: A B C
Measure 2 and 3: D C B - - -

B lasts 4 beats.

I put F and C under A note. Vertically, AFC. Now A does not sound like A any more. I put D under B, now B does not sound like B anymore. I don’t see I do anything wrong here chord-wise. But the whole thing sounds different from how melody sounds alone which is really a disaster. The chords changed the melody.

Comment: Which "B" are you adding the "D" to?

Comment: If you don't like the way your chords work with your melody then choose different chords.

Comment: The last B note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume we really are in `A` minor. That somehow the key is established.

Minor is type of *interval* quality between *two* pitches. For example, a *minor third*, which is two tones three semi-tones apart. In the key of `A` minor the third tone of the scale, which is `C`, is a minor third above the `A`. That particular minor third is what give the key its minor quality.

With the key `A` minor already established, if you play the single tone `A`, that single tone `A` should provide a sense of the *minor* quality, even though there are no other tones to make that explicit. This comes from the actual `A` and its *implied* relationship to the `C`.

Additionally, that single tone `A` has an implied relationship with the *tonic* chord of `A` minor. That chord is spelled `A C E`, and importantly the `A` is the *chord root* of that chord.

That makes the single `A` carry the characteristics of both the *tonic* of the key and the *chord root* of the key's tonic chord.

If you harmonize `A` with tones `A F C`, that is an `F` *major* chord. That chord's root is `F` while the `A` is the third of the chord. The interval between `F` and `A` is a *major* third.

So, the things that "sounds different" are:

- `A` changes its role from (at least implied) chord root to the chord's third.
- Relative to the root of the `F` major chord the `A` is part of a *major* third.
- Relative to the root of the (implied) `A` minor chord the `A` is part of a *minor* third.

> Why chords make melody sound different?

That phenomena is essential what the art of harmony is all about!

*Relative* relationships are very, very important in harmony.

When a pitch is harmonized the principle harmonic relationships to pay attention to are:

- the relationship of a pitch to the tonic of a key
- the relationship of a pitch in a chord to its chord root
- intervals, the relationship between two pitches

To illustrate how those three relationships differ let's consider pitch `F` in the key `C` major and harmonized in a `V4/2` chord (or chord symbol `G7/F`), which spelled vertically would be `F G B D`:

- `F` is the subdominant, the fourth scale degree, of `C` major
- `F` is a minor seventh above the chord root `G` in chord `G7`
- `F` is a major second below `G` in `G7/F`

Instead of just saying a pitch "sounds different", based on those different relative relationships, we can say things like: *`F` is a tendency tone in `C` major that wants to resolve to `E`, `F` is an unstable chord tone in `G7`, and `F` forms a dissonant major second when it is the bass in `G7/F`*.

> I couldn’t find answer to it on the internet. No one is talking about this.

A good, college level harmony textbook will cover all of these ideas.

Answer (score 4):

Played by itself, your melody will sound like A minor, and A will sound like the tonic — the first note of an A minor scale. This is influenced by the fact that it's the first note in your melody as well as by the fact that your melody is made of the first three notes of the A minor scale.

However, when you harmonize the A with F and C, you've created an F major chord. That's going to give a strong impression of F major, not of A minor.

Context has an immense impact on the perception of pitch, so one cannot effectively harmonize with arbitrarily chosen notes. This is one of the primary objectives of music theory: to explain how melody and harmony affect each other.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add to Aaron's answer:

> Sometimes, the chords just make the melody sound different.

You've stumbled onto the magic of "harmonization." And that's kind of the point of it. Start with a melody (monophony); then add chords to harmonize it. Right off the bat you've "enhanced" it (at least from a Western tonal perspective), brought it from 2D into 3D if you will. But there's usually a "simplest, obvious" choice. This stays close to the tonic, and uses "basic building block" chords like I, IV, and V. For example, I might harmonize your "A B C | D C B" melody simply with an A minor chord in the first measure and an E major (V) in the second measure.

But composers and arrangers have always enjoyed the challenge of making more inventive harmonic choices. Bach wrote [hundreds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chorale_harmonisations_by_Johann_Sebastian_Bach) of harmonizations of simple short melodies (chorales), and often wrote several different harmonizations of one given chorale melody, showing how there could be more than one approach. And yes, you could even harmonize a tune with a different key than the "obvious" one. (This is often done in with techno "remixes," harmonizing an originally major melody with minor.) I could probably recast your melody to be in C major, so that the first measure "A B C" could become IV, V, I.

> But the whole thing sounds different from how melody sounds alone which is really a disaster.

Is it, though? As PiedPiper suggested, if you don't like it, do something different. (And keep in mind, there's no rule that you have to harmonize at all! There's a lot of room for monophony even today.) But consider trying different harmonizations, until it changes your perception of the melody in a way that you *do* like.